# mySQL NOT IN SubQuery takes too long

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I would like to check streets using a table.

1. the query is not optimal
2. the query takes much too long

Can someone help me

```
SELECT id, strasse, plz
FROM `adress`
WHERE strasse NOT IN (
    SELECT street
    FROM post_plz
    WHERE `street` like adress.strasse AND plz like adress.plz
)
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using aleft join between the table and check for not mactching values

```
SELECT id, strasse, plz 

from `adress` 
left join  post_plz on strasse = street
  AND `street` like adress.strasse 
    AND plz like adress.plz
WHERE street is null
 LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: This query works just as well or just as poorly. Apparently the zip codes are not checked properly!?
However, the runtime had not improved (about 80 seconds)

Only when I declared the column `street` as index, the script ran within 0.4 seconds.

It does not run perfectly, but for my purposes it is enough.

Thanxx

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id, strasse, plz
FROM adress
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM post_plz
                   WHERE post_plz.street = adress.strasse 
                     AND post_plz.plz = adress.plz )
-- ORDER BY {expression}  
LIMIT 5
```

Without ORDER BY the query returns non-deterministic output (two query executions may produce different outputs). So it is strongly recommended to add some rows ordering.

The indices `post_plz (adress, plz)` and `adress (strasse, plz, id)` must improve.